# Exibição do MasterDetail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Como faço para exibir o MasterDetail acima do toolbar? 
Um exemplo do que quero é o MasterDetail do app Play Store que aparece até na barra que fica o horário.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WhoGO.Views.MasterDetail.Main"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:WhoGO.Views.MasterDetail"
             MasterBehavior="Split"
                  >
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MainMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <pages:MainDetail />
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o xaml das views? e onde você inicializa ele.

Comment: Editei com meu mainpage acredito que seja isso que pediu @AlexsandroTeixeira desculpe pela demora tive uns problemas com a faculdade e só pude retomar meu projeto agora, espero que possa me ajudar ainda.